# MathType 7 SDK for VBA

Tags: vba, sdk, mathtype

I am trying to find a MathType 7 SDK for VBA. I found that there was a MathType SDK but it is no longer supporting(as mentioned in http://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_desktop/mathtype-sdk) for MathType 7. Is there a MathType 7 SDK available for VBA ?

Comment: Sorry you got down voted, I think it is a very good question.

Comment: It's probably because this isn't a *specific programming problem*, more of a request for research.  @SMeaden if it makes you feel any better, both our answers were down-voted too...  (but I'll +1 your effort anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

[This is too big to be a comment but not satisfactory as an answer (yet) but I will amend if we make progress.]

`VBA` typically interacts (though not always) via COM (Component Object Model) Type Libraries.  So I'd look for an entry in the Tools->References dialog box.  The website does look promising in that MathType has an OLE (Object-Linking and Embedding) interface which is an intricate set of COM interfaces.

Do please report back if you find a Tools->Reference that looks like MathType.

Comment: @S Meaden,I already checked the reference dialog but there is a one reference called MathTypeCommands. But there is no any valuable functions like the previous MathTypeSDK. For an example in previous MathTypeSDK there is a valuble API call called "ExportEquationsInfo" which  converts math equations to one specific format. But in MathTypeCommands its call as "ExportEquationDlgInfo" but there is no any properties to pass the parameters. I think its only return the values we defined in the MathType ExportEquation dialog. So I don't see this "MathTypeCommands" as a important one for the developers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [direct-download link](https://www.dessci.com/en/dl/MathTypeSDK6.9.zip) to the **MathType 6.9 SDK** discussed [here](https://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/).  It [appears](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/default.htm) that there is no SDK for version 7... but the version was only released a couple weeks ago.  ...So recently the developer hasn't updated their website yet.  Another site mentions that the Beta version of the MS Office add-in is "coming soon".

[image: img]

I've never used the application but the included documentation describes samples and source code viewable in Microsoft Word VBA...

> The following test functions are available on the SDKTest toolbar above (in Word 2003). To see the source code for these functions, bring up the Visual Basic Editor via Alt-F11 on Windows or Option-F11 on the Macintosh.
>
> Before running any of these tests, you must create a reference to either the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the MT6SDK.dot template, depending on the bitness of your Office installation. Bring up the VB Editor, select this document, SDKTest.dot, and then select Tools >References. Place a check mark next to MathTypeSDK. If MathTypeSDK is not in the list, select Browse, navigate to the Templates\Win\32, Templates\Win\64 folder or Templates\Mac folder under the MathType 6 SDK folder, and select MT6SDK.dot.
>
> ...
>
> **`vTestVarSub()`**
>   Click on the equation below, and then click the `TestVarSub` button on the toolbar. You will be prompted for text to change from and to, and the resulting equation will be inserted in front of the existing one. Repeat three times, changing `<var1>` to `a`, `<var2>` to `b`, and `<var3>` to `c`, and you will end up with the quadratic formula.
>
> [image: img]

Comment: Thanks fro the update. But I am not looking for a office add-in. I am looking for a MathType 7 SDK if it exists.